# How to enumerate Spring java configuration classes?

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I'm using Spring's Java-based configuration in my application. I have a root configuration class that imports a bunch of other configurations, each which may import more configurations and so on:

```
@Config
@Import(AnotherConfig.class)
class RootConfig {
    // beans
}

@Config
@Import(YetAnotherConfig.class)
class AnotherConfig {
    // beans
}

@Config
class YetAnotherConfig {
    // beans
}
```

I then bootstrap the system by declaring a `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` in my `web.xml` file whose `contextConfigLocation` is set to `RootConfig`.

**Is there a way to determine the full set of configuration classes that has bootstrapped my application?** Some function like this (might take a subclass for `ctx`...):

```
List<Class> readConfigClasses(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    // what goes here?
    // should return [ RootConfig.class, 
    //                 AnotherConfig.class, 
    //                 YetAnotherConfig.class ]
}
```

---

**Update**: @axtavt's answer gets most of the way there, returning the actual configuration objects themselves, which are instances enhanced by CGLIB in my case. Grabbing the superclass of these proxies does the trick:

```
List<Class<?>> readConfigClasses(final ApplicationContext ctx) {
    List<Class<?>> configClasses = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
    for (final Object config : 
           ctx.getBeansWithAnnotation(Configuration.class).values()) {
        configClasses.add(config.getClass().getSuperclass());
    }
    return configClasses;
}
```

Comment: Do you need this at runtime, or just development? Turning on full Spring logging is usually enough to work out (by manual inspection) which configuration classes were loaded.

Comment: @artbristol, at runtime ideally...

Comment: You could try looking at the `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor`, but without knowing your exact requirements, it's tricky. Are you absolutely sure you need to do this?

Comment: @artbristol, the list is used to allow runtime inspection of the exact configuration of the application (which is more of a framework itself rather than a simple app).

Comment: sounds complicated! Are you sure the configuration shouldn't be informing the application of the necessary information? Rather than the app being coupled to its configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Configuration` classes are managed by Spring like regular beans, therefore you can enumerate them as `ctx.getBeansWithAnnotation(Configuration.class)`.

However, I'm not sure how would it work in complex cases (`@Bean`s in non-`@Configuration` classes, etc).